# Deepened/Slowed Voice With Voodoo-Cursed Soul?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Often during Halloween events, one of the funniest things in the game for me occurs in the form of heavies and scouts and the like obtaining deepened/slowed-down voice commands and death/pain sounds.

I was sure it was because of the cursed [voodoo souls](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Voodoo-Cursed_Soul), so I went and bought a few, but I can't seem to figure out the voice.

Surprisingly the only reference I can find that even mentions the voice modification is on the wiki: "The souls also affect the classes' voices, making them sound slower and deeper, and give the Scout and Soldier special voice lines." But I hear no difference from my lines, and *most* of the time when following another soul player (whether or not I have Halloween items on) I still hear no difference. Does it need to be Haunted quality or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those Voice Modifications are from the Halloween Spells in TF2. [A wiki article is here if you'd like to read more](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Halloween_Spells), but I'll sum it up for you.

There are 9 class specific spells that alter your voice, one for each class, and 1 all class spell (Voices from Below). The 1 all class spell isn't a standalone spell, but the byproduct when a class specific spell is applied to an all class cosmetic. These spells are unobtainable for now (only during Halloween) but you can purchase items that have those effects on the market still.

- Halloween Spell: Scout's Spectral Snarl
- Halloween Spell: Soldier's Booming Bark
- Halloween Spell: Pyro's Muffled Moan
- Halloween Spell: Demoman's Cadaverous Croak
- Halloween Spell: Heavy's Bottomless Bass
- Halloween Spell: Engineer's Gravelly Growl
- Halloween Spell: Medic's Blood-curdling Bellow
- Halloween Spell: Sniper's Deep Downunder Drawl
- Halloween Spell: Spy's Creepy Croon

So while the Voodoo Cursed Souls do not change your voice to low by default, a Halloween Spell such as the one listed above can modify the cosmetic so that it does lower your voice (on Halloween servers).

Comment: Thanks, perfectly explained right when I thought I might as well have been hallucinating the voices!